# How to start over with a clean gems install for jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I've been working on a blog using Jekyll so I installed Ruby with this command from the Jekyll doc:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-dev build-essential
```

Then I installed the gems directory to my home folder. I tried out a lot of different themes and just run `bundle install` when my terminal said I was missing any dependencies. Now I have a lot of packages installed inside the gems folder. Is there a way for me remove unnecessary gems and start over without uninstall gems?

Comment: Simply delete them from file explorer or with a `rm -rf ~/path/to/gems/*`. 

If you're starting to develop with ruby, you definitely have to look at [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) which allows you to easily run any ruby version you want.

Comment: Can you post the full backtrace errors you got? But also see answer I've posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is highly recommend to not use system ruby but use a ruby version manager. One reason is that you won't have to use `sudo` before your gem commands.

If you want to remove all your current gems you should be able to just do

```
gem uninstall --all
```

But you might need to prepend it with `sudo gem uninstall --all`

If you intend to do any longer term work / multiple projects with ruby, I recommend using RVM.  You can find [detailed install instructions here](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)

Some prefer [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation) however it's install instructions seem to be focused on MacOS, so if you're on linux, I dunno.

Comment: Thank you. I intend to use ruby for my blog so I'll definitely check out RVM.

Comment: @Kingle I highly recommend using RVM.  It will make your life easier.

Answer (score 4):

You can just run:

```
gem uninstall [gemname]
```

to remove them one at a time.

Comment: this answer made me say to myself... "ain't nobody got time for that!"